# How to Format grep Output When Saving to a Variable

Tags: linux, bash, grep

If I grep our syslogs for a specific term, I get a nice output of those logs matching my term and each entry on a separate line.

If I save that to a variable so I can use it in a script as such:

```
results=$( grep "term" logs )
echo $results
```

then all the logs run together and are not human readable.

How can I make it look cleaner so when I do `echo $results`, I can actually read the output?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote it:

```
echo "$results"
```

This preserves all the whitespace, instead of using it for word splitting.

In general, you should almost always quote variables, unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: Perfect! That did the trick!!! Thank you!